# Django inlineformset create duplicated queries

Tags: django, forms

I have a form where you add products to the warehouse. Warehouse is a foreign key. My view duplicates the database query which causes timeout of the server.

```
def warehouse_in(request):
    catalog_doc = CatalogDocument.objects.all()
    contractor = Contractor.objects.all()
    currency = Currency.objects.all()
    if request.POST:
    form = WarehouseInForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        warehousein = form.save(commit=False)
        warehousein_formset = WarehouseInFormSet(request.POST, instance=warehousein)
        if warehousein_formset.is_valid():
            warehousein.save()
            warehousein_formset.save()
            return redirect('catalog.views.warehouse_in_list')
else:
    form = WarehouseInForm()
    warehousein_formset = WarehouseInFormSet(instance=WarehouseIn())
return render(request, "catalog/templates/warehouse_in_form.html", {
    'form': form,
    'catalog_doc': catalog_doc,
    'contractor': contractor,
    'currency': currency,
    'warehousein_formset': warehousein_formset,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Info from ddtb:

SELECT ••• FROM "catalog_product" WHERE "catalog_product"."id" = 1
Duplicated 3 times.

Comment: You have issues in code formatting. Please fix it.

Comment: The duplicated query you show `SELECT ••• FROM "catalog_product" WHERE "catalog_product"."id" = 1`  should be very quick. Running it three times instead of once should barely be noticeable, and shouldn't cause the server to timeout.